# Show NavDrawer Scrim only under the support.v7.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

If you look at the Google Play Store app, they have scrim enabled (the darkness that overlays when you open up the drawer. In addition to this, they are showing the scrim over the actionbar, but not dimming the nav drawer icon or the title. Is there an easy way to get this effect?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>


</LinearLayout>

<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="start|left"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:name="com.jawnnypoo.material.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Normal
[image: Normal]

See how they are only scrimming the actionbar, with the icon and text untouched
[image: Only scrimming parts of the actionbar, not all]

What it looks like for me
[image: What it looks like for me]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if its the correct solution but I did this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Toolbar -->

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- content -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.jawnnypoo.material.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|left" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted, as the actionbar does not receive any of the scrim, but it does fix the problem with the scrim appearing on top of the toolbar. Thanks a bunch! Also, I edited your answer as some of the linear layouts were unneeded. Thanks a bunch though for this alternate solution